# Database Query crashes when null value is returned

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to squash a bug in my web application. Basically I am trying to implement a restaurant reservation system. The user selects how many people in their party, the sitting (lunch or dinner) and the date. The system then queries my database to let the user know if there is availability. It works if there are some people already booked in the restaurant but if the query returns a NULL value (i.e the restaurant is empty), the system crashes. I have never had to deal with NULLs before like this and I am at a loss on how to handle this error in the code so the user can make a booking. I have commented my code as best as I can. Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

```
protected void AvailabilityButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create SQL Database connection
    // New sql connection and command
    SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection();
    myconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=STUDENT2;Initial Catalog=HarryBistro;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = myconn;
    myconn.Open();

    //Check that selected date is today or later
    if (Calendar1.SelectedDate <= DateTime.Today)
    {
        SuccessFailureLabel.Text = "Please select a date in the future";
        SuccessFailureLabel.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create variables from user input
        string SelectedBranch = BranchDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string SelectedSitting = SittingDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();
        int SelectedDiners = Convert.ToInt32(DinersDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        string SelectedDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");


        //Query to find out how many people have already booked into selected restaurant on selected date on selected sitting 
        cmd.CommandText = "select SUM(Number_Of_Seats) from RESERVATIONS where Sitting = '" + SelectedSitting + "' and Branch_ID = '" + SelectedBranch + "' and Date_Of_Booking = '" + SelectedDate + "' ";

        //Assign the value of the people in the restaurant to a variable
        int peopleinrestaurant = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        //Query to find out how many people the selected restaurant seats 
        cmd.CommandText = "select SUM(Capacity) from BRANCH where Branch_ID = '" + SelectedBranch + "'";

        //Assign the value of the people in the restaurant to a variable
        int branchCapacity = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        //add the amount of people in the party to the restaurant occupancy and assign to a variable
        int totalOccupancy = peopleinrestaurant + SelectedDiners;

        if (totalOccupancy <= branchCapacity)
        {
            //Show success message
            SuccessFailureLabel.Visible = true;
            SuccessFailureLabel.Text = "Booking available. Please proceed.";

            //enable customer details text boxes so the customer can proceed                 
            ConfirmBookingButton.Enabled = true;
        }

        else
        {
            //Show failure message if booking over capacity. Show user how many seats are available
            SuccessFailureLabel.Visible = true;
            SuccessFailureLabel.Text = "Cannot proceed. There are only " + (branchCapacity - peopleinrestaurant) + " seats available.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do yuo get an error? At first glance, it seems your peopleinrestaurant should simple have a value of 0 when there are no bookings, not null.
That said, you can check if an object is NULL simple with if (object == null).

Comment: The `ExecuteScalar` may return null, which cannot be cast to `int`. You should check it's return value before casting.

Comment: I stand corrected. SUM() _does_ return null if no records are found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check for null before casting the value to int.

```
//Assign the value of the people in the restaurant to a variable
var obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

int peopleinrestaurant = obj != null ? (int)obj : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the return null or not by using

```
isnull(your query,replacement_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle NULL values specifically. NULL is not 0, so you can't do calculations with it. There are several ways to deal with NULL, but one way which is nice if you want to work with numbers is to add ISNULL() to the sql query.

```
SUM(ISNULL(NumberOfSeats,0))
```

However, as was stated, SUM() should never return NULL and should ignore NULLs, so I don't think your issue is in that very spot.

Comment: SUM() _does_ return NULL if no records are selected to sum. I just tested it and was surprised :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the easiest solution is probably not to have your queries return NULL:

```
select COALESCE(SUM(Number_Of_Seats), 0) from RESERVATIONS where ...
```

Comment: +1 for using COALESCE. That keyword deserves more attention. After a simple test i found that SUM() _does_ return NULL If there are no records to sum, so this is indeed a good answer (and the best in my opinion :) )

Comment: The advantage of COALESCE is that it works on (almost?) all databases (Oracle has NVL instead of ISNULL for example) and that you can have multiple arguments (first non-NULL value is returned). Assuming MS Sql Server as database, ISNULL works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
int peopleinrestaurant = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

to

```
int peopleinrestaurant = cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null ? 0 : (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Your query is returning null, and the problem is not on the query but in your data manipulation at c#.

Comment: This way you execute the command twice, better to assign the command result to an object once, then check if that is null or not.
I'm still not sure why SUM() would return NULL though...